# How to make an incoming call silent while the phone is in general mode?

Tags: lenovo, silent-mode

Now I am using Lenovo K8 plus.

How to make incoming call sound to silent mode while mobile in "general" mode.

On Xiaomi Redmi mobiles, if a call coming with sound, I just flip the phone and it will go to silent mode. This feature is available on Lenovo smartphones?

Comment: In Motorola devices and perhaps in other near-stock Android ROMs too, pressing the power button once turns off the sound for the incoming call. Try it and let us know whether it works.

Comment: I know that @Firelord. I want to make it without press any button. For example - Just rotate the phone or hide the screen using hand or shake the phone.